# Using the new operator to create objects/dependencies vs. using DI containers

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

What's so bad about manually wiring up dependencies via constructor injection and what's so great about using a DI container (`container.Resolve<T>()`) as against that?

I mean, apart from the fact that you have to type a few more keystrokes every time you need to create your dependent object and supply it with all its dependencies.

In fact, having a central registry like a DI Container provides can be a heck of a lot more confusing and take away control from you.

I've had this question and another one (below) for some time, but I guess Mark Seemann's article titled [Service Locator is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) got me to finally type this question here.

So, my other question is:

What if there's a dependency that itself needs some dynamic (say user supplied) input for its construction? Say, like:

```
class Dependency : IDependency
{
  public Dependency(string userInput) { }
}

class Dependent
{
    IDependency _dependency;

    void DoSomething()
    {
      var container = new MyFavoriteContainerFromTheMarket();

      Console.Write("Hey, user. How are you feeling?");
      var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

      // Do DI containers have overloads for Resolve instead of for Register
      // that accept parameters to be passed to constructors?
      // In other words, what if I don't know the constructor parameter
      // value at the time of registration of the dependency but only
      // get to know it just before I have to resolve/instantiate the
      // dependency? Do popular DI containers of today have overloads
      // for that? I assume they must
      _dependency = container.Resolve<IDependency>(userInput);
    }
}
```

Overall, doesn't it feel like DI Containers take away control from you? Wouldn't it just be okay to manually wire up dependencies in some cases?

Sure, I understand sometimes it is easy and saves you typing and creates for a cleaner, more terse code snippet, but having it all mixed up -- some dependencies managed by a container and some you have on your own that you manually supply -- all makes it so confusing and forces you to remember which one is which, and thus makes maintenance more difficult, wouldn't you agree?

**Update**

Oh, wait. I just realized my whole example was convoluted. I had meant to call the Resolve from client code in the main(). The code I should have originally posted with this question should have been like this:

```
class Dependency : IDependency
{
  public Dependency(string userInput) { }
}

class Dependent
{
    IDependency _dependency;

    public Dependent(IDependency dependency)
    {
      _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var container = new MyFavoriteContainerFromTheMarket();

      container.Register<IDependency>(new Dependency(/* I want this to come later */));

      container.Register<Dependent>(new Dependent(), 
       new ConstructorInjection<IDependency>());

      Console.Write("Hey, user. How are you feeling?");
      var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

      // It appears I can't do this as it makes perfect sense
      // to have the whole tree of dependencies known at the time
      // of registration.
      var dependent = container.Resolve<Dependent>(userInput);

      dependent.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

I don't know what that update makes of this previous discussion then. It just looks like some idiot (me) not having though out the question in his head before asking. Asking the question itself forced the right answer, which @Maarten confirmed and was trying to help me with.

Sorry, @Maarten. I wasted your time. :-)

Comment: You shouldn't try to resolve an instance by calling the container with a run-time value. See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/30/Dontcallthecontainer;itllcallyou/. Instead use abstract factories, see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/.

Comment: Upgraded my comment into an answer.

Comment: @Maarten I understand AbstractFactories and the whole gammut of patterns. So, you're confirming that if I have a run-time value, a DI container isn't the best choice, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't try to resolve an instance by calling the container. You should use constructor injection to inject your dependencies. Mark Seeman refers to this as [Don't call the container, let it call you](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/30/Dontcallthecontainer;itllcallyou/).

To solve your problem of creating an instance of an injected type with a run-time value, use [abstract factories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/).

So your example can be solved like this:

```
class Dependency : IDependency
{
  public Dependency(string userInput) { }
}

interface IDependencyFactory {
    IDependency Create(string userInput);
}

class DependencyFactory: IDependencyFactory {
    IDependency Create(string userInput) {
        return new Dependency(userInput);
    }
}

class Dependent {
    public Dependent(IDependencyFactory factory) {
        // guard clause omitted
        _factory = factory
    }

    private readonly IDependencyFactory _factory;

    void DoSomething() {
        // Do not call the container, let it call you.
        // So no container usage here.
        //var container = ...

        Console.Write("Hey, user. How are you feeling?");
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        var dependency = _factory.Create(userInput);
        // There you go!
    }
}
```

Comment: And configure the DependencyFactory implementation with the DI Container, right? So, in effect, what you're saying is, if I have a run-time value to be passed into the ctor of a dependency, don't register the dependency with the container. Instead, create a factory and register that with the DI container. My question remains: is it *possible* to have runtime values resolved via a container at the time of instantiating/resolving a dependency? And that it not good to do? Or is it just impossible as in DI Containers don't allow that?

Comment: Oh, wait. What did I just type. If what I typed were true, you'd still have to pass the runtime value to the container because it would then need to instantiate the factory. So, you're saying, don't use the container at all. Question: why not? Is it not at all possible for a container to supply runtime values at the time of instantiating dependencies or is it just not a good thing?

Comment: I'm using Simple Injector mostly, and that does not support to create instances based on a run-time value. The theory behind this is that the dependency graph/composition root should be fixed once it has been created, which sounds logical to me.

Comment: And no, the container doesn't need the run-time value to create the factory. It is the factory that needs the run-time value, when it's Create method is called.

Comment: In reply to your last comment, I think we're mixing our comments up. I am not implying that in this particular case, as per the code you wrote, that the container needs the runtime value. I am saying, "if you'd registered the factory with the container (which was implied by my first comment, and which obviously now I realize would have been stupid and convoluted), the container would still need the runtime value to resolve the factory, which would not have solved anythinng." Is that right?

Comment: *Re: composition root must be fixed once created.* I am therefore hearing this message. Please confirm if this is what you're trying to say. "If you have a known dependency that can be instantiated without any information that will change or be available at run-time, go ahead and use a container. If not, use an abstract factory instead." Is that about what you're saying?

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit difficult this way. Summarized: I have come to understand 2 rules about DI: 1) Do not call the container, let the container inject your injectables 2) If you need a run-time value to create an instance of an injectable, then the container cannot produce it, so create a abstract factory that can produce it when required, and register the factory with the container.

Comment: So following those 2 rules, you should never call the container in your code since that means you are coupling your code to a specific container. Your code should be unaware the a container is used.

Comment: Thank you. I think you're saying what I understand you're saying. Just one thing, though. In this case, i.e. in the case of the code you provided, there wouldn't be a need to reference the container at all. So, the Hollywood principle you mentioned, though a very valid one, would probably not apply to this particular depdendency, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52672/discussion-between-maarten-and-water-cooler-v2)

Comment: Just a stupid question from a newbie. It makes me feel that something is cached using DI? is it true? are we caching something even very insignificant?

Comment: @batmaci Ask a new question seems the best thing to do.